# Acumatica Report: How to populate Vendor Location as parameter?

Tags: acumatica

I have multiple branches/Locations for Vendors and need it as parameter but when I tried to populate the lookup it returns empty.

**Report Parameter**

Location View name I used:

```
=Report.GetFieldSchema('Location.LocationCD')
```

**The result**

[image: Acumatica Location Parameter]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse an existing DAC but for more control you may create a Parameter DAC

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using System;

namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
    public class APVendorParameters : IBqlTable
    {
        #region ActiveVendorID
        public abstract class activeVendorID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }

        [Vendor]
        [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Vendor.status, NotEqual<BAccount.status.inactive>>),
            Messages.VendorIsInStatus,
            typeof(Vendor.status))]
        public virtual int? ActiveVendorID { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region VendorLocationID
        public abstract class vendorLocationID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
        [PXDBInt]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<Location.locationID, Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Optional<activeVendorID>>>>), SubstituteKey = typeof(Location.locationCD), DescriptionField = typeof(Location.locationCD))]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Location")]
        public virtual Int32? VendorLocationID { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

In report add 2 parameters:
VendorID (string) ViewName=Report.GetFieldSchema('APVendorParameters.ActiveVendorID')

LocationID (string) ViewName=Report.GetFieldSchema('APVendorParameters.VendorLocationID,VendorID')

The secret stais in

> ,VendorID')

syntax

Comment: Thank you. I'm newbie with customization and creating new DAC and when I tried I got an error "Cannot resolve the table name: [PX.Objects.AP.APVendorParameters]". Do I need to add new table?

Comment: This error is because you execute the DAC into a Select BQL. The only place you put it on report is Report.GetFieldSchema nothing else.

Comment: It seems I messed with updating the table of the report after re-publishing it and just "Refresh All" then input Parameter View name again and now it works. Thank You!!.